# Grouping two different observables of two different classes rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have two Observables emitting data of 2 different classes :

1.User class :

```
{
"id"=>25,
"username"=>"Chris",
.. other data 
}
```

2.UserWebsocket class

```
 {
     "user_id"=>25,
     "age"=>25,
      .. other data 
  }
```

I want to merge and group the two observables by user_id or id attribute . So that the result of merging and grouping type is :

```
[User|undefined,UserWebsocket|undefined]
```

To more illustrate the question, I made a simple marble diagram :

[image]

**How this can happen ?**

Comment: Looks like you can just use `combineLatest`. Maybe use `startWith(undefined)` fore each source Observable.

Comment: @martin The issue that combineLatest  won't group them by user_id or id.

Comment: So what output you want to get?

Comment: @martin  Array of Combined User and UserWebsocket.  But the User and UserWebsocket should combined based on user_id and id.  User.id == UserWebsocket.user_id. Otherwise make the not  combined object paired with undefined.

Comment: @JasemAl-Yafie https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy

Answer (score 2):

As martin's comment suggests use combineLatest and set a starting value for each part. Assuming you have got `myUser$` and `myUserWebsocket$` observables you could use the following code to combine them. At first add a starting value and store the observables in new ones. Combine them with `combineLatest`. You have to subscribe to un*cold* the `combined$` observable.

**UPDATE**

Another approach is using `merge` and combine it with `withLatestFrom`.

```js
// Using RxJS v6+
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, map, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Your allready defined observables named e.g. myUser$ and myUserWebsocket$
// Add a starting value, since if user fires, websocket has no value yet.
const user$ = myUser$.pipe(
  startWith(undefined)
)
const userWebsocket$ = myUserWebsocket$.pipe(
  startWith(undefined)
)

const combined$ = merge(
  user$,
  userWebsocket$
).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(user$),
  withLatestFrom(userWebsocket$),
  map(([[merge, latestUser], latestWebsocket]) => {
    if (merge.user_id) { // merge is typeof userWebsocket, make sure user does not have user_id property
      if (latestUser && merge.user_id === latestUser.id) {
        return [latestUser, merge];
      } else {
        return [undefined, merge];
      }
    } else if (merge.id && !merge.user_id) { // merge is typeof user
      if (latestWebsocket && merge.id === latestWebsocket.user_id) {
        return [merge, latestWebsocket];
      } else {
        return [merge, undefined];
      }
    }
  })
);

combined$.subscribe([user, websocket] => {
  console.log(user, websocket);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a concern about how combineLatest group them by the user_id or id attribute. Because combineLatest  might combine them without caring if user_id and id  are equal. What I ask is to combine them if user_id == id (see second result) , otherwise make not combined objects with undefined corresponding  object (see first and last result)

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look.